# Nvidia Prime in powersave mode corrupts screen

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, 15.04, suspend

I have an ASUS ux303ln with Xubuntu 15.04 that hosts Nvidia 840M. Aiming for longer battery life, I want to use the Intel graphics, so i do

> prime-select intel

as root and that's OK.

The problem is when the laptop resumes from sleep - if I am with the Intel driver, the screen is not repainted - it is grey or just the last desktop image - I cannot regain my session and have to restart lightdm or the computer.
Tested with Nvidia drivers 340.76, 346.59, 352.21 and noveau.

Anyone has an idea what could cause this?

Comment: This must be related to intel driver, Nvidia blob is unrelated. And also acpi specifics of your laptop and kernel modules. It is hard to tell. You can report a bug to launchpad.

Comment: Yeah, I guess, I am wondering if I can do any more tests. It is going to land as a bug, though.